# GTK3 - Catch error when GdkDisplay is unavailable

Tags: gtk, gtk3, gdk

Given the following code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GdkDisplay *display = gdk_display_open(":2");

    gtk_main();

    return(0);
}
```

How can you catch the error, when the X server for display :2 is no longer running?
The exact error is:

```
Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :2.
```

Comment: Do you mean catching the error code? Catching the error is just a matter of checking that display is not `NULL`.

Comment: Just the error. The problem is when I have other code that depends on the GdkDisplay, like `g_signal_connect`. I don't know how to catch the error in this case. Also, it will still cause the whole program to exit, even if you don't use the GdkDisplay pointer like in the code I posted.